# form hidden value not working?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a simple table that prints our the list of videos and plays them when you click on the row.  I have a delete button to delete the corresponding video in the row.  But for some reason when you click on any video it will only delete the last one in the list.  I can look at the source on the page and the video_url seems to be correct.  Any ideas?

Here is the majority of the code:

```
<?php
// Dont allow direct linking
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');
//get current user
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
// get a reference to the database
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();

function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        echo $problem;
    }
    return $data;
}

if (isset($_POST['delete_video'])) {
    $video_url = check_input($_POST['video_url']); //value here is always just the last row in the table!!!
    echo $video_url;
    $query_delete_video = "DELETE FROM `#__videos` WHERE `video_url`='$video_url'";
    $db->setQuery($query_delete_video);
    $db->query();
}

//list all details of the camera including camera_name
$query_videos = "SELECT #__videos.video_url, #__videos.video_size, #__videos.video_datetime, #__videos.video_length, #__cameras.camera_name
    FROM #__videos INNER JOIN #__cameras using (user_id, camera_id) 
    WHERE #__videos.user_id=".$user->id." ORDER BY #__videos.video_datetime DESC";
$db->setQuery($query_videos);
//get number of cameras so we can build the table accordingly
$db->query();
$num_videos = $db->getNumRows();
// We can use array names with loadAssocList.
$result_videos = $db->loadAssocList();


echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";
?>
<link href="recordings/recordings.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer/example/flowplayer-3.2.6.min.js">  </script>
<?php

echo "</head>";
echo "<body>";
?>

<?php
if (!isset($result_videos))
{
    //TODO check if query failed
}
else 
{
    if ($num_videos == 0)
    {           
?>
        <div id="cc_table">
        <table id="webcam-table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Camera Name</th>
                <th>Camera Details</th>
                <th>Video Options</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <td colspan=3><b><i><center>You currently have no videos created. Start monitoring today!</center></i></b></td>
        </table>
        </div>
<?php
    }
    else
    {       
?>


        <div id="cc_table">
        <form name="myform" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="POST">

        <table id="webcam-table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Camera Name</th>
                <th>Camera Details</th>
                <th>Video Options</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

<?php

        for($i=0;$i<$num_videos;$i++)
        {
?>              
                <tr onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $result_videos[$i]["video_url"]; ?>');">
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $result_videos[$i]["camera_name"]; ?> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Date Created: <?php echo $result_videos[$i]["video_datetime"]; ?> <br>
                        Video Size: <?php echo $result_videos[$i]["video_size"]; ?> bytes <br>
                        Video Length: <?php echo $result_videos[$i]["video_length"]; ?> secs
                    </td>
                    <td>

                        <input type="submit" name="delete_video" value="Delete" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="video_url" value="<?php echo $result_videos[$i]["video_url"]; ?>" />
<?php

        }
            echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";
            echo "</form>";
            echo "</div>";
    }
}

?>

<div id="player" style="display:block;width:320px;height:240px;background-image:url(recordings/landscape.jpg)"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function DoNav(theUrl)
{
//document.write(document.location.href = theUrl);
flowplayer("player", "flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", theUrl);
}
</script>

<?php

echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post the HTML? I suspect you've got multiple hidden input fields on the page, all with the same name. If that's the case, only the last one that loads on the page will register as a valid hidden input. A better way to do it would be to set a data attribute on the delete button, and then add a JS click event to that delete button. Something like this:

```
<button class="delete" data-video_url="youtube.com/abcd">Delete ABCD</button>
<button class="delete" data-video_url="vimeo.com/xyz">Delete XYZ</button>
```

and then when someone clicks on a .delete button, you send the data-video_url value to the PHP script via POST. A jQuery example might look like this:

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).data('video_url');
    $.post('/delete.php', { video_url: video_url }, function() {
        // Do something on success
    });
});
```

Another way to do it is to simply make each button its own form:

```
<form method="post" action="delete.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="video_url" value="url_goes_here">
   <button>Delete</button>
</form>
```

Hope that helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the name of the hidden field is not unique (for every iteration in the loop a new hidden field with the same name is created). How should the script know which row you want if all of them has the same name?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not seem to name the hidden values properly.

You should use $i to name the variable.

```
input type="hidden" name="video_url<?php echo $i; ?>"
```

then in handler you can do

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
  $kv = array();
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // check here which one begins with video_url
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Ah I see but then what would I do in the code that processes this?    $video_url = check_input($_POST['video_url']);

Comment: You can check for values beginning with video_url in the handler. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php