# form with hidden type in table

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to find a way to generate a table from a list in the DB.  I also want to have a submit button to delete a selected video in the table.  Here is the post with the code:

[form hidden value not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218617/form-hidden-value-not-working)

A solution was provided with jquery but was wondering if there was another way to go about this?

Comment: Can you elaborate re what you're looking for?

Comment: so you need it with core javascript..?

Comment: Well right now I've been avoiding javascript, but if that is where I have to go then so be it.  Really I just need to create a table of the list of videos.  Then when someone clicks the delete button in the row it will delete.  The link has all the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work without any Javascript:

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<$num_videos;$i++)
{
?> 
[…]
<td>
  <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="video_url" value="<?php echo $result_videos[$i]["video_url"]; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="delete_video" value="Delete" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"/>
  </form>
</td>
[…]
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: That does work!  But I always thought this was not cross browser compatible placing a form inside a table?